# Does CloudWatch perform SNMP monitoring?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, snmp, amazon-cloudwatch, health-monitoring

CloudWatch can be used to perform system monitoring(AWS resources) & application monitoring on AWS resources.

Does CloudWatch rely on SNMP mib(of AWS instance) to monitor the metrics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, CloudWatch doesn't support SNMP monitoring. But you can use some external tools, which will read SNMP metrics and it will put metrics to the CloudWatch.

For example, you can use [customized collectd](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cloudwatch-plugin-for-collectd/) with the [SNMP plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:SNMP).

Answer (score 3):

No.  CloudWatch collects all these metrics from the hypervisor on the physical host that is running your instance.  It does not communicate with any processes running inside your instance, SNMP or otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

No definitely not. CloudWatch standard EC2metrics are hypervisor-level and not reported by the instance. If you put the instance in a Security Group that blocks ALL outbound network traffic, the metrics still update. That also explains why CloudWatch metrics don’t include any OS-level stuff like memory utilization, free disk space, etc.

You can install a CloudWatch agent on the instance that pushes additional metrics (like memory utilization and free disk space), but that communicates over HTTPS like all the other AWS APIs.  The CloudWatch API is well documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html

Furthermore, SNMP is typically a LAN protocol.  So if CloudWatch was using SNMP it would have an IP address in your VPC. CloudWatch does not have a VPC endpoint by default.

Comment: Does CloudWatch service uses some API to talk to Hypervisior?

Answer (score 1):

No, CloudWatch can´t get SNMP directly, but you can use other solutions to "collect" traditional SNMP data into CloudWatch.

Follow reference:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/snmp-monitoring-using-amazon-cloudwatch-and-elastic-logstash/